# How can I disable "global' search in the Salesforce1 (SF1) hamburger menu?

Tags: global-search, salesforce1-app

I am exposing a single lightning component tab in SF1 and have a profile that limits object exposure to only the relevant objects (no standard objects). This works fine. However, global search in SF1 allows a user to reach custom object records and while they don't have edit rights on those records, they can view them and it makes the UX in SF1 odd. Is there a way for me to disable that component?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is **NOT** possible to disable the global search in Salesforce1. You can however control which objects show up in Salesforce using the solution mentioned on [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27690/how-to-remove-customize-custom-objects-from-salesforce1-menu) thread.

Quoting the relevant text here

> Description When a customer has access to a standard or custom object
>   via the + (tabs listing) ONLY but cannot access that object via an
>   application, they will notice that these objects are not available in
>   the Salesforce1 left menu.
>
> Resolution Many users associate the tabs (objects) in Aloha with the
>   objects available in Stage Left in S1. When a tab is not available in
>   the Aloha UI via one of the available applications, that object will
>   not be shown within the Salesforce1 Stage Left.
>
> Users experiencing this issue should:
>
> 1) Click on the + to the right of the visible tabs within any
>   application 2) Choose 'Customize my tabs' 3) Select any appropriate
>   application and ADD the Standard or Custom object to the 'Available'
>   column 4) Save
>
> Now, the added objects should appear under the Salesforce1 Recent
>   Items section.

Comment: Thank you Gaurav, however, My use case is limiting access to which objects can be searched in SF1 while maintaining read/view all for them in the desktop. I probably can only go as far as I have using navigation limitations.

Comment: Just checking, Gaurav - behaviour still the same in 2019?